# Не удаляется объект

Tags: unity3d

После попадания пули проигрывается анимация и объект не удаляется(синие шарики), выдает ошибку

```
 public GameObject ImpactEffect;
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{

    if(collision.gameObject.tag == "walls")
    {
        Instantiate(ImpactEffect, transform.position, transform.rotation);
        Death();
    }
    
 
    if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Enemy")
    {
        collision.gameObject.GetComponent<Enemy>().Damage(damage);
        Instantiate(ImpactEffect, transform.position, transform.rotation); // скорее всего тут проблема
        Destroy(ImpactEffect);
        Death();
    }
    
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Вы пытаетесь удалить префаб, как я понимаю.
Попробуйте сделать примерно так:

```
    GameObject go = Instantiate(ImpactEffect, transform.position, transform.rotation);
    Destroy(go);
```

Удалится последний созданный элемент, полагаю :)

Comment: Sergey, попробовал ваш вариант, пулька удаляется до анимации(попадание есть но анимации попадания нету)

Comment: Destroy(go, 0.2f); Дописал так и заработало)